# Mongo suffering from a huge number of faults

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm seeing a huge (~200++) faults/sec number in my mongostat output, though very low lock %:

[image]

My Mongo servers are running on m1.large instances on the amazon cloud, so they each have 7.5GB of RAM ::

```
root:~# free -tm
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7700       7654         45          0          0       6848
```

Clearly, I do not have enough memory for all the cahing mongo wants to do (which, btw, results in huge CPU usage %, due to disk IO).

I found [this document](http://www.scribd.com/doc/56271132/MongoDB-Performance-Tuning) that suggests that in my scenario (high fault, low lock %), I need to "scale out reads" and "more disk IOPS."

I'm looking for advice on how to best achieve this. Namely, there are LOTS of different potential queries executed by my node.js application, and I'm not sure where the bottleneck is happening. Of course, I've tried

```
db.setProfilingLevel(1);
```

However, this doesn't help me that much, because the outputted stats just show me slow queries, but I'm having a hard time translating that information into which queries are causing the page faults...

As you can see, this is resulting in a HUGE (nearly 100%) CPU wait time on my PRIMARY mongo server, though the 2x SECONDARY servers are unaffected...

[image]

Here's what the Mongo docs have to say about page faults:

> Page faults represent the number of times that MongoDB requires data not located in physical memory, and must read from virtual memory. To check for page faults, see the extra_info.page_faults value in the serverStatus command. This data is only available on Linux systems.
>
> Alone, page faults are minor and complete quickly; however, in aggregate, large numbers of page fault typically indicate that MongoDB is reading too much data from disk and can indicate a number of underlying causes and recommendations. In many situations, MongoDB’s read locks will “yield” after a page fault to allow other processes to read and avoid blocking while waiting for the next page to read into memory. This approach improves concurrency, and in high volume systems this also improves overall throughput.
>
> If possible, increasing the amount of RAM accessible to MongoDB may help reduce the number of page faults. If this is not possible, you may want to consider deploying a shard cluster and/or adding one or more shards to your deployment to distribute load among mongod instances.

So, I tried the recommended command, which is terribly unhelpful:

```
PRIMARY> db.serverStatus().extra_info
{
    "note" : "fields vary by platform",
    "heap_usage_bytes" : 36265008,
    "page_faults" : 4536924
}
```

Of course, I could increase the server size (more RAM), but that is expensive and seems to be overkill. I should implement sharding, but I'm actually unsure what collections need sharding! Thus, I need a way to isolate where the faults are happening (what specific commands are causing faults).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but a couple of things jump out.  After setting `db.setProfilingLevel(1)` you need to take those queries and run `explain()` on them.  Most likely these queries are not using indexes and doing full collection scans.  Your secondaries being idle is another cause of concern, depending on your application setting `slaveOk=true` can help by putting some of the load on the secondaries. I would make sure your indexes are ok first though or you are just spreading the misery to the secondaries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't really know what your data/indexes look like.

Still, an important rule of MongoDB optimization:
Make sure your indexes fit in RAM. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ#IndexingAdviceandFAQ-MakesureyourindexescanfitinRAM.

Consider that the smaller your documents are, the higher your key/document ratio will be, and the higher your RAM/Disksize ratio will need to be.

If you can adjust your schema a bit to lump some data together, and reduce the number of keys you need, that might help.

Comment: It seems that I missed the part on "one index per query." I was also being pretty overzealous with my use of indexes around my schema, because I was unaware of the "must fit in RAM" constraint. Quick question about indexing best-practices though: when executing a query that also uses a sort() or limit(), should I index on those fields? How about when I have queries that search on multiple conditions (eg, {'age': 30, 'name': y}, is there any good way to decide which of the 2 columns (both?) should be indexed?

Comment: also -- after executing db.XX.dropIndexes(), is there anything I would need to do to recover resources / stop page faults on my mongo server? I dropped all my indexes and reindexed in a much more conservative manner, but am not seeing any improvement yet.

Comment: As for your first question. It's tough to answer these things generally. These are the constant questions we ask and tradeoffs we make with schema design. For compound indexes, if you are searching field A, or A,B or A,B,C then you can create a compound index on [A,B,C]. If you then search on B or C, it won't help you. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-CompoundKeys

Comment: So... I was certain this was the solution, since I recently added indexes, so I went through and did a dropIndexes() on ALL tables, but my memory usage remains @ almost 100% (per the free -tm command) and the CPU has not dropped... crap. FWIW, my totalIndexSize (across the whole database) is 600MB, much smaller than my 7.5 GB of RAM that is being consumed....

Comment: @ZaneClaes  So are you running queries against properties that are not indexed. And hence a full scan is required, and therefore you see a lot of faults? What if you search for specific _ids? (Uncheck my solution if you don't think it's the right fix.)

Comment: I guess the problem I'm having goes back to my original question: where are the faults occurring? I have 13 separate collections, each of them being hit by different queries by my node.js app. I'm attempting to go re-index them each intelligently, but without knowing WHY these huge # of faults are happening I cannot effectively determine how to isolate and fix the faults... attempting to just search for specific _ids may help in an isolated scenario, but my app does not run in such an isolated scenario ;)

Comment: After more inspection, I noticed that the "mapped" value in mongostat is huge (28g), much more than the size of all my collections (~5g). I recently deleted purged a lot on unneeded entries from a collection. Perhaps this explains my problem? Mongo is still mapping a huge amount of memory when only a small subset is needed?

Comment: yes, looks like your collection files are fragmented. you could try compacting them or running repairDatabase if you can have your app down or have replica set configured.  your mms shows only a few queries running during the page faulting (2 or 3). if you turn on profiling you should be able to see those queries and you can manually run each on mongo shell with .explain() to see why they may be inefficient.

Comment: After so many years but your discussion kept me interesting till the end. I would be so glad of you can write a conclusion of what finally happened and how did you solve it, I hope so.